# Getting date out of datetime value stored in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, count

I have added a field in my MySQL Database, which is a `DateTime` field.

Now when value get stored, it is like this:- `2012-03-31 12:13:42`

I have read in one of the forum that, if i need to fetch the date only out of the datetime i should use this query:- `SELECT CAST(`datetime_field`AS DATE) AS dateonly FROM etc...`

Now I actually want to count the number of fields for that date, where all the dates should be equal to today's date, So i did this:-

```
$todayDATE = date("Y-m-d");
$TCRTcount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE CAST(`customer_regdate` 
AS DATE) AS dateonly = '$todayDATE'";
$TCRTcount_QE = mysql_query($TCRTcount, $dacreint) or die(mysql_error());
$TCRTcount_QF = mysql_fetch_array($TCRTcount_QE);
$TotalCustomersAddedToday = $TCRTcount_QF[0];
```

I gives me the following error:-

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS dateonly = '2012-03-31'' at line 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `AS dateonly`, you can not use alias in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE CAST(`customer_regdate` 
AS DATE) = '$todayDATE';
```

alternatively you can also get the date from `DATETIME` column using `DATE()`.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE DATE(`customer_regdate`) = '$todayDATE';
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need to cast it and if you are always after today's date (i.e. the current date) you don't need to pass the date in from PHP, you could just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE DATE(`customer_regdate`) = CURDATE()
```

However there are reasons why you would want to pass in the date from PHP (testing for one) so you might want to stick with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE DATE(`customer_regdate`) = '$todayDATE'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can use `CURDATE()` MySQL function in your queries in stead of `date("Y-m-d")`